# Как сделать запрос ILIKE с переносом строки?

Tags: postgresql

Как добавить перенос строки в запрос ILIKE?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ILIKE '%ДЕТАЛИ\n%'
```

В базе лежит такое значение

```
"ДЕТАЛИ
Вторая строка"
```

Comment: Пробуйте `%ДЕТАЛИ\\n%`

Comment: или используйте concat + нужный символ через char (13,10,3338) - тут уже сами подбирайте нужный

Comment: Вот так не работает. Ничего не находит.

%ДЕТАЛИ\\n%

Comment: @manking - пробовали мой вариант?

Comment: Пробую. А можете пример скинуть?

Comment: Получилось вот так:

concat('%ДЕТАЛИ',''||chr(10)||'%')

Comment: Но этот не очень подходит. Если приходит строка с поисковой фразой, то придется  сильно заморачиваться. Есть ли иные варианты? Может с настройкой сервера?

Comment: @manking - вам что именно нужно находить? перенос строки? строку с переносом?